# Oracle Database 12c on Oracle Linux 7 - autostart, enabling connection as sysdba

Tags: oracle, linux, configuration

I've installed 12c on Oracle Linux 7 for my development work, as per document `Oracle Database Installation Guide 12c Release 1 for Linux (E41491-10)`. My previous experience with administering Oracle Database is version 8 on Novell Netware and 10gR2 on Windows x64 at my prevoius workplace. I have not worked with Linux too much, save for some simple services on Ubuntu.

This time I choose not to create database on installation, so I had to run Oracle Database Configuration Assistant to do so, because I needed some options that default database did not have. I've done everything by the book, but I encountered **problem one: ORACLE_HOME or ORACLE_BASE env vars were not set after creation.** I had to edit .bash_profile to set these.

Database was created in default location, which is `/home/oracle/app/oracle/oradata/<SID>`. It was started and configured with listener. Upon completion of database creation, I noticed **problem two: I can't connect to oracle instance using sqlplus / AS SYSDBA**. I am presented with `ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified`. As document `Oracle Database Error Messages 12c Release 1 (E49325-06)` states, I checked if TNSNAMES.ORA doesn't contain any errors in connect descriptor, but it doesn't. Full contents of this file are (KITET is my instance name):

```
KITET = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ORALINUX7VM)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER = SHARED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = Kitet)
    )
  )
```

I connected only by specifying `sqlplus <user>/<password>@<service_name>`.

After rebooting my virtual machine, I noticed **problem three: listener and oracle do not start automatically**. I can start listener by using `lsnrctl start`, but can't start up the database (can't connect using `/ AS SYSDBA`). I figured I could connect by specifying connection string with service_name, but I was greeted with `ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`.

After looking here and there on the internet, I found out that by exporting ORACLE_SID, I could alleviate "can't startup" problem, so I did just that by editing (again) `~/.bash_profile`.

**What I still need done**

I need listener and database startup automagically on boot, on Oracle Linux 7. Of course I am in posession of a document `Oracle Linux Administrator's Guide for Release 7 (E54669)` but there's no information on how to create startup scripts for Oracle Database and Listener. There's just info on starting and stopping EXISTING services. Of course I can't login to my VM box and startup services everytime I power it up.

Please assist.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my own research, google results and ansible's answer, I was able to come up with complete solution for Oracle Linux 7. Everytime you read `Kitet` - this is my Oracle Instance SID.

To start or stop database, `dbstart` and `dbshut` scripts are used respectively. They are located in `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`. Both of them need a parameter, which is `$ORACLE_HOME`. If there's no `$ORACLE_HOME` environment variable, first there's a need to set it (and some more) by running

```
. /usr/local/bin/oraenv
```

(note the preceding period, and it's not `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/oraenv`). Oraenv script will ask for a SID, which is needed to set correct $ORACLE_BASE. With this, using simply

```
dbstart $ORACLE_HOME
```

or

```
dbshut $ORACLE_HOME
```

will start and stop the listener and database.

To start listener using `lsnrctl` or start SQL*Plus using `sqlplus / as sysdba`, running `. oraenv` beforehand is also required, unless user wants to set manually some environment variables. If our linux box has only one instance, there's a possibility of automating running of `. oraenv` by editing user's bash profile. Enter

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

and type following lines (there's probably already `umask 022` entry in this file, as per `Oracle Database Installation Guide 12c Release 1 for Linux E41491-10`):

```
export ORACLE_SID=Kitet
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
. /usr/local/bin/oraenv
export NLS_LANG=POLISH_POLAND.AL32UTF8
unicode_start
```

Line one and three are self explanatory. Line two will make `oraenv` not ask for database SID and use exported variable. Line four is optional and will set your language preference for client connections (e.g. SQL*Plus or lsnrctl will speak in your native language, if available). Line five is needed for console to display accented characters, and is also optional.

**Automating startup and shutdown of Listener and Database**

1) Once the instance is created, edit the `/etc/oratab` file setting the restart flag for each instance to 'Y'. My line is as follows:

```
Kitet:/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1:Y
```

2) Next, create a file called `/etc/init.d/dbora` as the root user, containing the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 345 99 10
# description: Oracle auto start-stop script.
#
# Set ORA_HOME to be equivalent to the $ORACLE_HOME
# from which you wish to execute dbstart and dbshut;
#
# Set ORA_OWNER to the user id of the owner of the 
# Oracle database in ORA_HOME.

# path to oracle home (needed only to check if dbstart exists)
ORA_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1
# this is the user who installed oracle
ORA_OWNER=oracle

if [ ! -f $ORA_HOME/bin/dbstart ]
then
    echo "Oracle startup: cannot start"
    exit
fi

case "$1" in
    'start')
        # Start the Oracle database and listener:
        # Remove "&" if you don't want startup as a background process.
        export ORACLE_SID=Kitet
        export ORAENV_ASK=NO
        . /usr/local/bin/oraenv
        # at this point we have $ORACLE_HOME env variable set
        su $ORA_OWNER -c "dbstart $ORACLE_HOME" &
        touch /var/lock/subsys/dbora
        ;;
    'stop')
        # Stop the Oracle database and listener:
        export ORACLE_SID=Kitet
        export ORAENV_ASK=NO
        . /usr/local/bin/oraenv
        su $ORA_OWNER -c "dbshut $ORACLE_HOME"
        rm -f /var/lock/subsys/dbora
        ;;
esac
```

3) Use the chmod command to set the privileges to 750:

```
chmod 750 /etc/init.d/dbora
```

4) Associate the dbora service with the appropriate run levels and set it to auto-start using the following command:

```
chkconfig --add dbora
```

That's all. `dbstart` and `dbshut` should write to their respective logs at `$ORACLE_HOME/startup.log` and `$ORACLE_HOME/shutdown.log`. There also is `$ORACLE_HOME/listener.log`. There we can verify if and how instance and listener started and stopped. We could also use `ps -ax | grep ora` or `ps -ax | grep lsnr` to see if listener / oracle are running.

Comment: A few comments on configuring your Linux environment this way:

Comment: 1) The `$ORACLE_HOME/root.sh` script copies the `oraenv` script from `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/oraenv` to `/usr/local/bin/oraenv`; they are not different. `diff /usr/local/bin/oraenv /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/bin/oraenv` produces no output. 2) Oracle recommends not calling `oraenv` inside the .profile script for the Oracle software owner (the oracle user):  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/admin_ora.htm#UNXAR120. 3) The `dbstart` script does not require a parameter if you are just starting the databases.  Review the link/script at TLDP to see how this works with the listener.

Answer (score 1):

**How I Enable Autostarting of Oracle Database for Demonstrations and Development**

---

Here are the steps I have been using to enable autostarting of Oracle Database Enterprise Edition 10g, 11g or 12c during boot time of Oracle Linux 5 and 6. I also use these steps with Oracle Linux 7. These steps are useful for the kinds of demonstration and development setups that I typically need.

These steps are not needed for Oracle XE, since its install will prompt whether to autostart the DB and will configure the system automatically.

Create a new service script
Create a file /etc/init.d/dbora using dbora with content

```
#! /bin/sh -x
#
# chkconfig: 2345 80 05
# description: start and stop Oracle Database Enterprise Edition on Oracle Linux 5 and 6
#

# In /etc/oratab, change the autostart field from N to Y for any
# databases that you want autostarted.
#
# Create this file as /etc/init.d/dbora and execute:
#  chmod 750 /etc/init.d/dbora
#  chkconfig --add dbora
#  chkconfig dbora on

# Note: Change the value of ORACLE_HOME to specify the correct Oracle home
# directory for your installation.
# ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.1.0/db_1
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1

#
# Note: Change the value of ORACLE to the login name of the oracle owner
ORACLE=oracle

PATH=${PATH}:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
HOST=`hostname`
PLATFORM=`uname`
export ORACLE_HOME PATH

case $1 in
'start')
        echo -n $"Starting Oracle: "
        su $ORACLE -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart $ORACLE_HOME" &
        ;;
'stop')
        echo -n $"Shutting down Oracle: "
        su $ORACLE -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbshut $ORACLE_HOME" &
        ;;
'restart')
        echo -n $"Shutting down Oracle: "
        su $ORACLE -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbshut $ORACLE_HOME" &
        sleep 5
        echo -n $"Starting Oracle: "
        su $ORACLE -c "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart $ORACLE_HOME" &
        ;;
*)
        echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit
        ;;
esac

exit
```

Set permissions on the script

```
# chmod 750 /etc/init.d/dbora
```

Tell Linux to autostart/stop the service
On Oracle Linux 5 and 6 run:

```
# chkconfig --add dbora
# chkconfig dbora on
```

On Oracle Linux 7 run:

```
# systemctl enable dbora
```

Edit /etc/oratab
In /etc/oratab, change the autostart field from N to Y for any databases that you want autostarted.

Starting / Stopping the DB
The DB will start and stop at machine boot and shutdown.

Or it can be manually controlled with:

-On Oracle Linux 5 and 6 use:

```
# service dbora start
```

and

```
# service dbora stop
```

-On Oracle Linux 7, use:

```
# systemctl start dbora
```

and

```
# systemctl stop dbora
```

Starting Oracle Database 12c Multitenant PDBs
To also start all pluggable databases when the container database starts, run this in SQL*Plus as SYSDBA:

```
create or replace trigger sys.after_startup
   after startup on database
begin
   execute immediate 'alter pluggable database all open';
end after_startup;
/
```

Refer: [How I Enable Autostarting of Oracle Database for Demonstrations and Development](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-i-enable-autostarting-of-oracle-database-for-demonstrations-and-development)

Answer (score 0):

First, are you using the `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/oraenv` command?  This is what typically sets the ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME, and ORACLE_SID environment variables on a Linux system using the Oracle Database.  When connecting to an Oracle database from the command line in Linux, running `oraenv` should usually be your first step, as it will prompt you for the SID of the database you want to connect to, and set the ORACLE_[SID|HOME|BASE] variables based on that SID's entry in the oratab file (default location is usually `/etc/oratab`).  You'll need to source the script by using the `. oraenv` syntax so that the variables set by the script stay active in the current shell.The "oracle" user should already have `$ORACLE_HOME/bin` set inside its `$PATH` variable, so you can simply run `. oraenv` from the command line, provide the SID for the database, and then issue `sqlplus / as sysdba` to login successfully.  For other users besides the "oracle" user - after running the `root.sh` script as directed by the OUI during software installation, the `oraenv` script is copied to `/usr/local/bin/`, so other users are able to access `oraenv` to set the Oracle environment variables as well.

Configuring the `oratab` file correctly and calling `. oraenv` should solve your problems with being able to login to and startup the database (regardless of the listener).

Second, there is also a script called `$ORACLE_HOME/bin/dbstart` (and its companion, `dbshut`) that automatically starts the TNS listener and any databases in the `oratab` file that have a value of "Y" for that database SID.  You can and should use these two scripts to automatically startup and shutdown your Oracle databases; it is especially important to cleanly shut down any open databases before you turn off/shutdown/reboot the VM or server.

To start the TNS listener and Oracle databases automatically at system startup, you can write a simple bash script to call `dbstart` for you.  This usually involves placing the script in the `/etc/init.d/` folder; more details on how to write a script for various Linux distros that executes on startup has been answered in detail elsewhere on SE (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7793/bash-script-on-startup-linux).  TLDP also has a good example with direct references to the Oracle database (using `dbstart` and `dbshut`) - http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Oracle-7-HOWTO-6.html.  This references an older version of the Oracle Database using RHEL 5.0, but should still be relevant for your system.

Comment: I read about `oraenv` in Oracle Ins. Guide (8. Preferred postinstallation tasks) and since you mentioned it again, I read insides of that script and it explicitly mentions that it's **necessary** to run it with preceding period, like `. oraenv` not just `oraenv`. That's why when I ran it the wrong way I was not getting proper env. Env works properly now, thanks. I also found out about dbstart and dbshut and I created a startup/shutdown script that calls them, but Listener doesn't start, even though when launched from cmdline, it does. I'll read links you posted and will report back my status.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct, you need to source the `oraenv` command as you indicated.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.  Have you tried just manually executing the `dbstart` script without calling it inside another script?  Does that successfully start the listener?

Comment: I need to give it $ORACLE_HOME (`dbstart $ORACLE_HOME`) variable (or full path), else an error is raised, so listener is not started, but database is. Links you provided are only partly helpful, I needed to combine information from various sources. I will answer my own Q because there is not enougt space in a comment.